# dropzonejs accept action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Использую библиотеку *dropzonejs* для загрузки файлов. Мне надо, чтобы создавался файл `discussdesk.xlsx`.

Но когда я начинаю использовать опции библиотеки, он не создается.

В чём ошибка?

Собственно, сам код:

```
   <?php     $uploadedStatus = 0;
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        var_dump($_FILES);
        die();
            //if there was an error uploading the file
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
            } else {
                if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                    unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                }
                $storagename = "discussdesk.xlsx";
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $storagename);
                $uploadedStatus = 1;
            }
        }

        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>php excel to mysql</title>
          <meta name="description" content="php excel to mysql"/>
          <meta name="keywords" content="PHPExcel"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script src="dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropzone/dropzone.css">

        </head>
        <body>

        <section>
            <table width="600">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="font:bold 21px arial; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px 0 10px 0;">Download an Excel database</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px;" >
                    <div  class="target" style="visibility: hidden;">
                      <b>File Uploaded<b/><b>Do you want to upload the data  <a href='pourintobase.php'>Click Here</a><b/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="targetworks"  style="visibility: visible;"><b><?php print "Hello Mister, ".$userdata[0]['user_login'].". Successfully works!";?><b/></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="20%" style="font:bold 12px tahoma, arial, sans-serif; text-align:right; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px 10px 5px 0px; border-right:1px solid #eee;">Select file</td>
                  <td width="80%" height="196px" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee; border:dotted; border-color:#207347; padding:0px; margin: 0px;">
                    <div id="dropzone"><form id="filedrop" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" class= "dropzone"><div class="dz-message">
                          Drop files here or click to upload.
                    </div></form></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
                            <input type="submit" name="exit" value="exit"/>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
                Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
                    maxFilesize: 40, // MB
                    acceptedFiles: ".xlsx",
                    accept: function (done) {
                        $("div.target").effect("slide", "slow").css("visibility", "visible");
                        $("div.targetworks").effect("puff", "slow").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

даже в условие if не попадает.

Answer (score 1):

Если этот файл уже где-то существует, то попробуйте вот так:

```
var existingFile = {
name: 'discussdesk.xlsx',
size: file.src_size,
file_id: file.id,
url: file.url};
Dropzone.emit("addedfile", existingFile);
Dropzone.emit("complete", existingFile);
Dropzone.emit("thumbnail", existingFile, file.url);
```

Я примерно таким образом закидываю в дропзону ранее сохраненные файлы после перезагрузки страницы.